# Camera intent filter not working for nougat

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I have developed an application which is tracking images you click using camera. Till Marshmallow the photo is got tracked by the app but using the same code in Nougat the app cant track the new picture i click.

My CameraReceiver class is

```
 public class CameraReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 private String pathSplit;
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(intent.getData(),
            null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String image_path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_data"));
        String MediaType = intent.getAction().equals("android.hardware.action.NEW_VIDEO") ? "VIDEO" : "IMAGE";
        FilesObservers.postDataCreateEvent("CREATE", image_path, true,MediaType);
        cursor.close();
    }

}




public IntentFilter getCameraFilters() {
    IntentFilter lsIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    try {
        lsIntentFilter.addDataType("image/*");
    } catch (IntentFilter.MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    lsIntentFilter.addAction("com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE");
    lsIntentFilter.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
    return lsIntentFilter;
}

}
```

and in manifest

```
<receiver android:name="com.sys.observers.CameraReceiver" />
```

Comment: From API 24 it has been stopped supporting these broadcast.  But you can use the alternative for that using JobInfo and JobParameters. https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/background-optimization.html#media-broadcasts.

Comment: Hi @nTri , can you guide me how should be my code according to the link you provided, i have gone through but i couldn't understand. Thank You

Comment: target API version 23 work properly

Comment: Hi @VishalBhut , i need to made it work for nougat so i am targeting API 24, any sample code would be helpful.

Comment: hi @nTri, can you please say how to make use of JobInfo.Builder.addTriggerContentUri(JobInfo.TriggerContentUri)

Comment: @Rahul try to implement you code by following this tutorial, https://www.developer.com/ws/android/how-to-schedule-background-tasks-in-android-apps-using-the-jobscheduler-api.html

Answer (score 0):

> I have developed an application which is tracking images you click using camera

No, you are tracking the delivery of certain broadcasts. There is no requirement for those broadcasts to be sent by any camera app. Also:

- There is no requirement for a camera app to let third-party apps know when pictures are taken (in fact, doing so is a privacy flaw)
- There is no requirement for a camera app to save photos where third-party apps can access them

> Till Marshmallow the photo is got tracked by the app

For the particular camera app(s) that you tested, that certainly is possible.

> but using the same code in Nougat the app cant track the new picture i click

That is because those broadcasts [are no longer supported](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#bg-opt).